# Connect to HTTPS web service from Azure

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure, ssl-certificate

I have a web role in Azure that has to connect to an SSL-secured external web service.  When the application tries to connect to the web service, it's giving an error:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
>   with authority 'certname.organization.org'.

The certificate that it needs has been uploaded to Azure as a service certificate, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be properly referencing it or using it.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like your service client in Azure isn't happy with the SSL certificate of the external service you're calling - do you have control of that service?

You can test this by using the following to ignore SSL errors from your client in Azure:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    (obj, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Comment: I don't have control of it, unfortunately.  And when I test things locally (without using the Azure emulator), it connects and works fine.  It seems to be a permissions issue that Azure can't locate the proper certificate.  I did try your suggestion, and it worked so thanks.  However, it's more of a work-around than a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem intermittently as well. In my case it turned out that the network connection to get the one of the root certificates would sometimes time out. Then on future requests it would work again.

I ended up writing a custom callback that would let the particular certificate I was interested in work despite the errors, without affecting validation of other certificates. The below is my code for that. As you can probably tell, I'm trying to hit the Android Cloud-to-Device Messaging endpoint, and trying to work around problems with the wildcard cert that Google uses, but it should be generalizable. This also has all the logging I used to diagnose the particular error. Even if you don't want to force validation of the certificate, the logging code could help you decide how to proceed.

```
private static readonly Uri PUSH_URI = new Uri("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send", UriKind.Absolute);

/**
//The following function needs to be wired up in code somewhere else, like this:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateDodgyGoogleCertificate;
**/
/// <summary>
/// Validates the SSL server certificate. Note this is process-wide code.
/// Wrote a custom one because the certificate used for Google's push endpoint is not for the correct domain. Go Google. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">either a host name string, or an object derived from WebRequest</param>
/// <param name="cert">The certificate used to authenticate the remote party.</param>
/// <param name="chain">The chain of certificate authorities associated with the remote certificate.</param>
/// <param name="sslPolicyErrors">One or more errors associated with the remote certificate.</param>
/// <returns>
/// Returns a boolean value that determines whether the specified
/// certificate is accepted for authentication; true to accept or false to
/// reject.
/// </returns>
private static bool ValidateDodgyGoogleCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
    // Good certificate.
    return true;
    }

    string hostName = sender as string;
    if (hostName == null)
    {
    WebRequest senderRequest = sender as WebRequest;
    if (senderRequest != null)
    {
        hostName = senderRequest.RequestUri.Host;
    }
    }

    //We want to get past the Google name mismatch, but not allow any other errors
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)
    {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("Rejecting remote server SSL certificate from host \"{0}\" issued to Subject \"{1}\" due to errors: {2}", hostName, cert.Subject, sslPolicyErrors);

    if ((sslPolicyErrors | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine("Chain status errors:");

        foreach (var chainStatusItem in chain.ChainStatus)
        {
        sb.AppendFormat("Chain Item Status: {0} StatusInfo: {1}", chainStatusItem.Status, chainStatusItem.StatusInformation);
        sb.AppendLine();
        }
    }

    log.Info(sb.ToString());

    return false; 
    }

    if (PUSH_URI.Host.Equals(hostName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
    return true;
    }

    log.Info("Rejecting remote server SSL certificate from host \"{0}\" issued to Subject \"{1}\" due to errors: {2}", hostName, cert.Subject, sslPolicyErrors);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring SSL errors is one thing you can do.

But if it works on your machine, and it doesn't work on your instances it might also be that the certificate chain is incomplete on the instances. You'll need to open the certificate on your machine, go to **Certification Path** and export each certificate in the path.

Then, add these certificates to your project and have a startup task (.bat or .cmd file) add them to the trusted root CA:

```
REM Install certificates.
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root Startup\Certificates\someROOTca.cer
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root Startup\Certificates\otherROOTca.cer
```

Comment: Unfortunately since this is Azure we can't run anything on the command line, but I'll try your suggestion of breaking out the certificates in the chain.

Comment: Actually, you can run this using startup tasks: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas

Answer (score 0):

i added the cer to the root of my project and select "Copy Always" and use the following command to make azure connect to server with SSL self sign

```
 REM Install certificates.
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root startsodev.cer
```